# Do real-analytic functions that uniformly converge in all derivatives make something good?

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence, analytic-functions, analyticity

Given a sequence of real-analytic functions
$$f_n:(-\varepsilon_n,1+\varepsilon_n)\to\mathbb{R}$$
and assume that each of their derivatives converges uniformly on $[0,1]$:
$$\forall k=0,1,\ldots,\qquad f_n^{(k)}(t)\to g_k(t)\text{ uniformly on }t\in[0,1]$$
It would hence imply that $g_k=g_0^{(k)}$ and in particular, $g_0$ is a smooth function.

**My question is that**: is $g_0$ also real-analytic on $(0,1)$?

P.S. I see that it doesn't have to be analytic at the endpoints, for example, $f_n(t)=F(t+1/n)$, where $F(u)=e^{-1/u}$. We would have $g_0=F$ with $g_0(0)=0$.

Comment: No, take any non-analytic smooth function and look at $f_n = f \ast n e^{-\pi n^2 t^2}$ (convolution)

Comment: That's a great example. Thanks a lot!